# how to print innerHTML of all tds when click on any td in javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table, I want to print all inner html of table cells when I click on any cell, If I do this through button it's working fine but when I do this with click on cell it's throwing an error Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined.`

```
function funcName(){
   var allTds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var j=0; j<allTds.length;j++){  
        allTds[j].onclick = function(){
            var chekTds = allTds[j].innerHTML;
                console.log(chekTds);                
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please clear that on click on a cell, you want to print only that cell html or overall cells html?

Comment: You should add bracket '}' one time footer.

Comment: I want to print overall cells html

Comment: } i just forget to put here in site, it's there in my code

Comment: I have mentioned above in my question about all cells

Comment: var chekTds = allTds.innerHTML; showing in console "undefined"

Comment: where is your answer Anik Islam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this...

```
    function funcName() {
    var allTds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var j = 0; j < allTds.length; j++) {
        allTds[j].onclick = function() {
            var allTdsNew = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var k = 0; k < allTdsNew.length; k++) {
                console.log(allTdsNew[k].innerHTML);
                     }

                   }

               }
           }
```

Comment: this real works exactly I want thank you so much Anand

Comment: most welcome mohsin :)

Comment: This is very inefficient, *allTds* is a live collection, so there is no need to get it every time the function is called. Why not just put a single listener on the document and if a click comes from a TD, write the innerHTML of all TDs?

Comment: if you do that .., internal process will be same as this... because it has to bind with every td.

Answer (score 0):

You have onclick in you function. check this code.

```
<script>
function wokring(){
   var allTds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var j=0; j<allTds.length;j++){  
        var chekTds = allTds[j].innerHTML;
            alert(chekTds);                
    }
} 
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="wokring()">1</td>
        <td  onclick="wokring()">2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

remove this line....

```
allTds[j].onclick = function(){
```

Comment: so if I have hundred of tds then I have to place function in all you mean?

Comment: tds are generating dynamically

Comment: If auto generated than it will not be difficult to add onclick event on each.